# A cryptographic service provider (CSP)

Tags: c++, windows, service, cryptography

I can't run my own csp on Win10 but can run it on Win7 x86. I don't know why the problem. Do I need config how or sign with windows to run it on Win10? Please share your skill to me!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks your reply email! We have the token pki and want to develope CSP library to use them. We develop all function and now we need check them on Windows as win 7, 8, 10 and 11... When we configurate the CSP on win7, it is run to our CSP library but can't run it on Win10. I don't know why it don't run on Win10. Do you know what tool to check CSP , please share to help us. Thanks you so much!